# SwiftUI center list inside VStack

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the following code:

```
  var body: some View {
    
    VStack(alignment: .center, content: {
        Spacer()
        
        List {
            Section {
                Text("Row 1")
                Text("Row 2")
            } header: {
                Text("Header")
                    .font(.title3)
                    .padding()
            } footer: {
                Text("Footer")
                    .font(.body)
                    .padding()
            }

        }
        .listStyle(.insetGrouped)
        
        Spacer()
    })
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 50)
 }
```

The problem is this always places List at the top, no matter how many Spacers I add. How do I put the List in the center of superview?

Comment: `List` greedily takes all available space. You'd have to specify how tall you want it to be. Just the size of it's content?

Comment: That works, but how do I calculate height that takes care of header and footer?

Comment: @DeepakSharma How about specifying the height of the `Spacer`s then?

Comment: You could try measuring the content of the list with `GeometryReader`. See https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/11/04/how-to-use-geometryreader-without-breaking-swiftui-layout/

Comment: If you use Grid instead of List you get the desired alignment. But in that case, unfortunately, you loose the typical list layout and features.....

Answer (score 1):

It seems that a `List` reports its ideal height as 0, which is not very helpful. This prevents `.fixedSize` from being used to restrict it to its ideal height. A custom `Layout` that performs its layout based on the ideal height of its content will also not work (which is a shame).

However, another way to find the height needed by the `List` is to use a `GeometryReader` to examine the relative position of the items inside the list, in particular, the footer. This can then be used to set a `maxHeight` for the `List`:

```swift
@State private var maxListHeight = CGFloat.infinity
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { outer in
        VStack {
            List {
                Section {
                    Text("Row 1")
                    Text("Row 2")
                } header: {
                    Text("Header")
                        .font(.title3)
                        .padding()
                } footer: {
                    Text("Footer")
                        .font(.body)
                        .padding()
                        .background {
                            GeometryReader { inner in
                                Color.clear
                                    .onAppear {
                                        let maxY = inner.frame(in: .global).maxY
                                        maxListHeight = maxY - outer.safeAreaInsets.top
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(.insetGrouped)
            .frame(maxHeight: maxListHeight)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 50)
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

You will notice that the global coordinate space is being used to find the position of the footer, so the height of the `List` is computed by deducting the height of the top safe-area insets. These insets are measured by another `GeometryReader` that surrounds the `VStack`.

I was thinking that the outer `GeometryReader` could be avoided by using the coordinate space of the `List`. However, I discovered that the items in the `List` (or at least, the section footer) cannot reference the coordinate space of the container, so it always defaults to the global coordinate space.

What this means, is that if the `List` is not the first item in the layout then you would need to deduct the height of whatever comes before it when computing the height of the `List` from the position of the footer.

Comment: While it works, it seems there is no solution without using `GeometryReader`.

Comment: @DeepakSharma Yes, due to the way the `List` does not deliver useful information about its ideal size, I couldn't find any other way of getting the exact height. However, if it was my code, I think I would simply use an estimate of the height, which can be found with a little trial and error. If this expected height is then defined as a `ScaledMetric` then it will adapt to different text (font) sizes, so should work quite reliably. Then there would be no `GeometryReader` involved.