# Show button below the list or at the bottom of the view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a view which has a list and a button. The list could be short or long since the values within it are dynamic.

Incase of short list, I wish to display the button below the list, but incase of long scrollable list, the button should be bottom of the view i.e. the button should always be visible. I tried setting button as the footer of the section which works fine for a short list, but when list is long, button is hidden and user has to scroll to get to it.

How can I display button at the bottom of the screen when list is long?

***Current code:***

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let shortList: [String] = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"]
    let longList: [String] = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen", "Twenty", "Twenty One", "Twenty Two"]
    
    @State var showSheet: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                Section {
                    ForEach(longList, id: \.hashValue) { value in
                        Text(value).font(.body)
                    }
                } header: {
                    Rectangle().frame(height:0)
                }
                
                Section(footer: self.resetButton) {
                    EmptyView().frame(height:0)
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) { SheetA() }
    }
    
    private var resetButton: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
               // Do something
            } label: {
                Text("Reset").font(.body).bold().padding(.trailing, 5.0)
            }
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 50.0, height: 30.0)
            .padding(8.0)
            .background(Color.mint)
            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            .font(.headline)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Short List]
[image: Long List]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions:

1. **Put the reset button in a `toolbar` with placement `.bottomBar`**

```swift
List {
    Section {
        ForEach(longList, id: \.hashValue) { value in
            Text(value).font(.body)
        }
    } header: {
        Rectangle().frame(height:0)
    }
}
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .bottomBar) {
        resetButton
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

2. **Keep the `List` height to the minimum necessary**

If you want the button to be immediately below the list when the list is short, instead of it being at the bottom of the screen, then you could keep the height of the `List` to a minimum using the technique described in the answer to [SwiftUI center list inside VStack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77759636/20386264) (it was my answer).

In the case here, a hidden copy of the reset button could be placed in the `footer` of the `List` and the position of this hidden item can be used to adjust the list height:

```swift
@State private var maxListHeight = CGFloat.infinity

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { outer in
        let topInsets = outer.safeAreaInsets.top
        VStack {
            List {
                Section {
                    ForEach(longList, id: \.hashValue) { value in
                        Text(value).font(.body)
                    }
                } header: {
                    Rectangle().frame(height:0)
                } footer: {
                    GeometryReader { inner in
                        resetButton
                            .hidden()
                            .onAppear {
                                let minY = inner.frame(in: .global).minY
                                maxListHeight = minY - topInsets
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(maxHeight: maxListHeight)
            resetButton
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
        .background(Color(UIColor.systemGroupedBackground))
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) { SheetA() }
}
```

This requires a small change to `resetButton`, to prevent the background color from extending into the safe area:

```swift
.background { Color.mint } // instead of .background(Color.mint)
```

[image: Screenshot]

Getting the height to change dynamically when the items in the list are changed is a bit more tricky. You could try resetting the max height to `.infinity` whenever the items change and then using an `.onchange` handler to detect when the list has changed and compute a new height.

Comment: I don't always want it to be at the bottom. If the list is short, I want it to be right where the list ends or at the bottom if list is longer. If there is no better solution, I will probably will have to decide the button placement based on number of items in the list and the cell size.

Comment: Answer updated and alternative solution added.